# Failed startup of context com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, spring-mvc, servlet-filters

I am using Spring MVC,google app engine, admin sdk, cloud sql. 
I want to access (preferncesDao) dao class into Filter.
Below is my filter

```
public class NameSpaceGoogleSecurityFilter implements Filter
{
    @Autowired
    IPreferencesDao preferncesDao;

    public void init( FilterConfig filterConfig ) throws ServletException{
          SpringUtils.init(filterConfig.getServletContext());
          preferncesDao = SpringUtils.getPreferncesDao();
   }
}
```

Below is my SpringUtils class.

```
public class SpringUtils {

   private static ApplicationContext appContext;

   private static IPreferencesDao preferncesDao = null;

   public static void init(final ServletConfig config) {
       init(config.getServletContext());
   }
   public static void init(final ServletContext context) {
      if(appContext==null){
        appContext =
            (ApplicationContext) context.getAttribute(WebApplicationContext.ROOT_WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE);
      }
   }

   public static IPreferencesDao getPreferncesDao() {
      if(preferncesDao==null){
        preferncesDao=(IPreferencesDao) appContext.getBean("preferncesDao");
      }
     return preferncesDao;
   }

   protected SpringUtils() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
   }
}
```

When I start build process, It is throwing below exception

```
Failed startup of context com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext
  java.lang.NullPointerException.  
  Nullpointer at line  preferncesDao=(IPreferencesDao) appContext.getBean("preferncesDao");
```

How can i resolve above error ? is it right way to get dao object into filter ? if not what is correct way.?

Answer (score 2):

It is required to add below tag in web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Answer (score 1):

That purely indicate that ContextLoaderListener missing.

so add below code in web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>
          org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
```

For more details refer [this link](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-error-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-web-context-contextloaderlistener/)